# CMake doesn't link the object files

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files, sfml

Hello i am trying to build my SFML project using CMake but when i try to use multiple source files, CMake doesn't link the object files

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

project(PolygonPoints)
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS graphics window system audio REQUIRED)
file(
    GLOB
    SOURCES
    "src/*.hpp"
    "src/*.cpp"
)

add_executable(PolygonPoints ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(PolygonPoints sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system sfml-audio)
target_include_directories(PolygonPoints PRIVATE include)
```

This is my project structure:

```
PolygonPoints/
    src/
        main.cpp
        point.cpp
    include/
        point.hpp
    build/
        (...)
    CMakeLists.txt
    (...)
```

This is the error I get:

```sh
bayram@milkyway ~/Projects/PolygonPoints/build (main)> cmake .. && make && ./PolygonPoints
-- Found SFML 2.5.1 in /usr/lib64/cmake/SFML
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/bayram/Projects/PolygonPoints/build
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target PolygonPoints
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable PolygonPoints
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/PolygonPoints.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to `Point::Point(sf::Vector2<int>, sf::Vector2<int>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PolygonPoints.dir/build.make:117: PolygonPoints] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/PolygonPoints.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Did you implement the `Point::Point(sf::Vector2<int>, sf::Vector2<int>)` function in your point.cpp file. Perhaps you have a typo.

Comment: Do you get the same error message when you build your project without CMake?

Comment: @drescherjm Yes I did implement.

Comment: You may have to look at the Makefile. This is odd and unexpected.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I tried compiling in the commandline with `g++ -I include/ -c src/*.cpp && g++ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system main.o point.o` and I got the same error. Interesting I thought the problem was about CMake.

Comment: In that case it's probably a duplicate. You can check the link in my first comment.

Comment: There is **no implementation** of the given `Point` constructor in all your source files. This is what the error message is about. Something wrong with your `point.cpp`, but since you don't show it, we cannot help you in finding an error.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are right sorry I was pretty sure the error had something to do with CMake so didn't attach the source code. After playing with the code more, I realized the code also doesn't have anything to do with SFML.  At this point I am not sure whether I should create a new question with a code refined from SFML stuff or just edit this one.

Comment: I would delete this question and ask a new question containing a [mcve] without SFML and CMake. There already is an answer and some comments related to CMake. An edit would be confusing.

Comment: @ThomasSablik This seems reasonable. I am now deleting this question.

Comment: Turns out I can't delete the question directly when there is an answer. I flagged the question to be deleted with an explanation. I hope mods delete it soon.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful here:

```
file(
    GLOB
    SOURCES
    "src/*.hpp"
    "src/*.cpp"
)
```

As i understand it this is ran ONLY during cmake project configuration so if you have added a .cpp file later it will not be included with the build. You are much better to explicitly list your files in the executable as so:

```
add_executable(PolygonPoints 
    src/main.cpp
    src/point.cpp
)
```

When you add a file now you have to edit the `add_executable` which causes cmake to re-evaluate itself and regenerate the build/make files (depending on your generator) and thus files are always compiled as expected.

Comment: It's clearly described in the comments that this problem is unrelated to CMake and also occurs without CMake. It's also unrelated to SFML.

Comment: "@ThomasSablik I tried compiling in the commandline with g++ -I include/ -c src/*.cpp && g++ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system main.o point.o and I got the same error. Interesting I thought the problem was about CMake"